# Makefile variable yields different results

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I am working on a make-script for a hobby OS project. When playing with the script I noticed that two different variable expansions of (almost) the same variable yields different results (even though they are placed 'directly' after each other). I'll provide the important part of the makefile and the result when ran.

Makefile:

```
####################
#      KERNEL      #
####################
.PHONY: kernel

KERNEL_OBJS  = $(patsubst %.c,%.o,$(wildcard kernel/*.c))
KERNEL_OBJS += $(patsubst %.asm,%.o,$(wildcard kernel/*.asm))
KERNEL_OBJS += $(DRIVER_OBJS)
KERNEL_NAME  = kernel32.elf

kernel: $(KERNEL_OBJS)
    @echo $^
    @echo $(KERNEL_OBJS)


####################
#     DRIVERS      #
####################
.PHONY: drivers

DRIVER_OBJS := $(patsubst %.c,%.o,$(wildcard drivers/*/*.c))
```

Makefile executed via terminal in the following manner (GNU Make 4.2.1):

```
make kernel
```

And this yields the following result:

```
kernel/kmain.o kernel/boot.o
kernel/kmain.o kernel/boot.o drivers/vga/vga.o
```

The output lines are of-course from the two 'echo lines' in the kernel recipe. It is worth mentioning that all variables used in this code-snippet are used **here and only here** in the otherwise larger make-script. Two regular suffix rules are used to build the *KERNEL_OBJS* but they should not alter the output here in anyway. Apart from the suffix rules, this snippet and it's variables is completely seperated from the rest of the script.

Any ideas why the two variable expansions differ? Yours, Mikael.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The big difference between the two contexts is that the prerequisite list is expanded *immediately* when the makefile is parsed, but the recipe is only expanded later, when make is about to build that target.

When make first parses your makefile it finds this line:

```
kernel: $(KERNEL_OBJS)
```

It expands this variable immediately.  When the variable is expanded the `DRIVER_OBJS` variable has not been set yet, so it is the empty string and you get this:

```
kernel: kernel/kmain.o kernel/boot.o
```

Then make finishes parsing all the makefiles and as part of that, the `DRIVER_OBJS` variable is set... but that doesn't matter to the above line because it's already been expanded.

Now make decides it wants to build the `kernel` target and in order to do that it has to expand the recipe:

```
@echo $^
@echo $(KERNEL_OBJS)
```

Here `$^` is the prerequisite list: `kernel/kmain.o kernel/boot.o`. Now `KERNEL_OBJS` is expanded and now `DRIVER_OBJS` is set, so you get the full list.

See [How make Reads a Makefile](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Reading-Makefiles.html#Reading-Makefiles) for full details on when expansion happens.

Comment: What do you think about this method of pulling in a whole globbed list of files as prerequisites as a dependency concept, especially if the referenced place isn't a read only directory?

Comment: Thank you @MadScientist!

Comment: I personally never use wildcards in my makefiles.  I always list all the source files directly.  The list of source files is not changed so often that this is a burden, and I prefer to know exactly what I'm compiling into my programs and not allow some random source file that I happened to create as a test or similar to get in the way.  However, that's just my preference.

Answer (score 0):

You can activate second expansion and then use it in the dependency:

```
.SECONDEXPANSION:
kernel: $$(KERNEL_OBJS)
```

Comment: Very nice! Thank you for the new knowledge!